# Fetch the data from JSON response

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, ios8

I am getting JSON response like this

```
[{"UserId":250,"Response":"success"}]
```

I used below code to fetch the UserId

```
  NSDictionary *jsonDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

userId = [jsonDict1 valueForKey:@"UserId"];
```

but i am getting user id in the form of   `(   250   )`  i need to get the data without  parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root object in your JSON is an array you can tell this as there are square brackets around the object (which uses curly braces).

When you call `valueForKey:` on an array it will return a new array that contains the results of calling `valueForKey:` on each of the elements.

If you just want to get this first item you need to do this

```
NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData 
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                     error:&error];

userId = results.firstObject[@"UserId"];
```

---

```
               Array
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
v                                     v
[ {"UserId":250,"Response":"success"} ]  
  ^                                 ^
  |                                 |
  +---------------------------------+
         1st object in array
```

Comment: @Zaph this is unsafe without a check on count especially with networked data

Comment: Yes, one should make a check. An explicit check is better practice to better handle errors.